# missing js file after module files added

Tags: magento2, module, requirejs

New to the magento 2
I am getting error JS while loading page, Any one know what exactly this issue.

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/modulename.js'
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\modulename\vendor\magento\framework\App\StaticResource.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\modulename\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\modulename\pub\static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#3 {main
```

Comment: How do you call your custom js?

Answer (score 0):

Check your js config in requirejs-config

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            yourJS:       'NameSpace_ModuleName/js/yourfile',
            yourJS2:      'NameSpace_ModuleName/folder/yourfile2'       
        }
    },

};
```

Real Path to your js in module is 
first one : NameSpace_ModuleName/view/area/web/js/yourfile.js 
yourJS2 NameSpace_ModuleName/view/area/web/folder/yourfile.js

area is `frontend`, `base`, `adminhtml`

Call `yourJS`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['yourJS'], function(){ // Do something here });
</script>
```